# Making Laravel 8 validation rules optional to allow empty fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

I have a Laravel 8 application. In a form I have two fields that are both optional.

I set the validation rules like so:

```
class ValidateAddEmptyTopic extends FormRequest {
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'title'     => 'string|max:255',
            'init_url'  => 'url'
        ];
    }
}
```

However it still requires the fields to be included, even without the required attribute. How can I make the fields optional while still having the validation rules applied when data is submitted from the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields) validation too.

```
return [
        'title'     => 'nullable|string|max:255',
        'init_url'  => 'nullable|url'
    ];
```

The field under validation may be `null`. This is particularly useful when validating primitive such as strings and integers that can contain `null` values

Answer (score 0):

**Hope it will slove your problem**

```
class ValidateAddEmptyTopic extends FormRequest {
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'title'     => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'init_url'  => 'nullable|url'
        ];
    }
}
```